# Extract text between two links in HTML through Java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, epub

I am trying to retrieve the text data from an ePub file using Java. The text of the ePub file lies within a HTML file that is formatted something like this -

```
<h2 id="pgepubid00001">Chapter I</h2>

<p>Some text</p>
<p>Another line of Text</p>

<br/>

<h2 id="pgepubid00001">Chapter II</h2>

etc..
```

Before opening this file I already know the id of the Chapter I need to extract and can find the id of the next chapter too. Because of this I thought a logical approach would be to attempt to parse it in a SAX parser and extract the text in each paragraph until I reached the link of the next chapter. But this is proving quite a task.

Of course, everything is dynamic so there is no set link to go to etc. The HTML is semi-strictly formatted so I didn't expect parsing to be so much of a problem. Can anyone recommend a good way to extract the text needed?

The solution needs to be **JAVA ONLY**, no other languages can be used. I am looking to implement this in an Android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know ids of the chapters, why not use String.indexOf ?

```
start = text.indexOf("<h2 id=\"pgepubid00001\">");
end = text.indexOf("<h2 id=\"pgepubid00002\">");

whatYoureLookingFor = text.substring(start, end-start)
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: Is there a straight forward way to take the HTML out and put it into a string?

Comment: So you want to remove html tags as well? try String.replaceAll("<[^>]+>",""). Anyways, it might be a good idea to parse it. Use jtidy to convert html to a valid xml.

Comment: I actually just went ahead an loaded it into a String through an InputStream then took out the html. Pretty straight forward once you gave me the idea! Thanks a lot man, been bashing my head off the wall for a while with this one and I don't know why I didn't think of that before :)