# Extract String from html page which is in Assets folder?

Tags: java, android, string

I have couple of html pages in my assets folder, i am able to open them and get them in a string. My problem lies ahead of it, I just to extract text between certain tags. For example if i am having a line in my html page as `<h3>Hello have a nice day</h3>` inside h3 tag.

I just want to get "Hello have a nice day". Till now i tried it to string functions but no success. How can i achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I got the solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690219/extract-text-between-two-links-in-html-through-java)

Comment: Jsoup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817882/using-java-to-extract-a-single-value-from-an-html-page/10817974#10817974

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.fromHtml()`, pass the html source and it will return only the text..

check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to read html files, then everything should be easy. If it's simple html page you can use xpath to parse it and retrieve whatever you want, or you can use some libaries such as jsoup to parse the html.